# fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver

Tags: boot-failure, uefi

Ubuntu fails to boot. (It was working fine for the last moth.)

Selecting "recovery mode" shows the message:

```
fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
```

However, after this message is shown, the system still does not boot.

Answer (score 2):

1. Whilst on the GRUB selection screen (where you select your operating
   system, recovery mode, etc) use the arrow keys to navigate to the normal boot entry, bur rather than pressing enter, press the letter 'e'.
2. Delete the line `gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode`
3. Press F10 to boot

If this doesn't work, try again, but first disconnect all USB devices (other than keyboard!) and extra monitors if you have them.

If you can not reboot, once booted, run the following, so that hopefully you won't have to do the steps above everytime you boot.

```
sudo grub-install
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: [This worked for me, but I have seen different solutions on the internet]

Comment: I've tried this, but my system still doesn't boot. Where are the other solutions you mentioned @fluteflute?

Comment: Removing this line did the trick but the change is not saved between reboot even after grub-install and update-grub. I used grub-customizer to edit grub configuration and make the change permanent.

Answer (score 1):

While trying to install linux mint 17, I stuck in the same problem. In my case there was no gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode line in grub so what I did is to add nomodeset BEFORE quiet splash.

Check that https://askubuntu.com/a/207177/34553 for what nomodeset is.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this  by editing `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`

there is an if clause that writes the line:

```
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
```