# What does `nomodeset` do

Tags: nomodeset

Since installing Ubuntu 12.10 I have been playing around trying to get my Radeon HD 5450 gpu to work with the proprietary driver, as from the start installing the driver meant losing unity.

I won't list the steps I took as it is not a requirement to answering this question.

After taking one measure and then installing fglrx-updates, upon reboot the system hung at the purple screen. So I decided to boot using `nomodeset`

I edited

```
quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

to look like this

```
quiet splash nomodeset
```

Making this change I am then able to log in with Unity and the proprietary driver installed and performing well. I would go as far as to say it performs better than it did in 12.04

`fglrxinfo` reads

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5000 Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11903 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Please note the way I have added `nomodeset` It had been a while since I have had to do this so it was done from memory.
When looking for an answer to this question I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) and discovered that my edit was supposed to go from

```
quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

to

```
nomodeset $vt_handoff
```

What has my `nomodeset` edit done? The only thing wrong that I have noticed is that I don't get the plymouth Ubuntu logo screen when booting.

If that is the only trade-off I am happy to make the edit permanant.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

The answer can be found here : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

> **nomodeset**
>
> The newest kernels have moved the video mode setting into
> the kernel. So all the programming of the hardware specific clock
> rates and registers on the video card happen in the kernel rather than
> in the X driver when the X server starts.. This makes it possible to
> have high resolution nice looking splash (boot) screens and flicker
> free transitions from boot splash to login screen. Unfortunately, on
> some cards this doesnt work properly and you end up with a black
> screen. Adding the nomodeset parameter instructs the kernel to not
> load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.

Comment: So I am not losing out on performance by making the edit permanent, only on the splash screen? It would be nice to know that my graphic card issue is sorted.

Comment: You said correct. :-)

Comment: @NikTh: I actually detect a problem when I add nomodeset permanently.  I cannot detect a second screen anymore. Do you have any suggestions for that? Without nomodeset, I end up with a purple screen and cannot boot ubuntu anymore.

Comment: @Cleb , `nomodeset` is a temporary solution/workaround until fixing the graphic card, either by installing a driver (if exits) or upgrading to a newer version. It can be cause several problems depending on Kernel version, hardware...etc. I would suggest to open a new question here on AskUbuntu or in ubuntuforums.org, describing the problem in details.

Comment: @NikTh: I now posted my question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/631339/ubuntu-14-04-alternative-to-nomodeset-second-screen-is-not-detected-which-gra Hope you can help :)

Comment: @ChrisCarter I might loose performance if you fallback to the VESA driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do/249579#249579

So you should search how to check which driver is actually used.

Answer (score 20):

Many open source drivers have removed support for non-kernel mode setting, so in those cases when you use nomodeset you will end up falling back to the very basic VESA un-accelerated driver.  This is very much a performance and feature hit.

nomodeset should not have any effect on the proprietary (fglrx/nvidia) drivers.  They don't have this kind of kernel mode setting.

Removing "splash" is what got rid of the Plymouth boot*splash*.

Radeon just finished removing support for "User Mode Setting" (what nomodeset forces the computer to use) relatively recently, but with Intel graphics it has been the case for a while. 
http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-announce/2012-November/002093.html