# Catch-22: No Ubuntu to install AMD driver for initial Ubuntu install through Win8.

Tags: 12.10, boot, drivers, ati, windows-8

Without going into unnecessary detail, I purchased a laptop with Win8 pre-installed, spent a couple days troubleshooting/learning how to get Ubuntu 12.10 to load up from both a flash drive and a DVD-R.

I can boot to the GRUB2 screen, but either choice of trying to install Ubuntu or loading it without install sends me to blank/black screen.  The bits I've found from other threads has pointed to this possibly not having an Ubuntu-specific driver installed for my graphics card.

Here is what I need to install:
http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-linux-x86.x86_64.zip

The problem is that this unzips to a .RUN file...

How do I install a .RUN file from within Windows 8?  Any ideas?  I'm new at this so I might be behind on some of the technical jargon... will try my best.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you get into the tty (command line)? Try pressing CTRL+ALT+F2.

Answer (score 2):

You really can not install that driver into the live session. You need to first install Ubuntu, then install the driver from the command line.

**If you can not install from the desktop CD, you may have to use the Alternate CD. The alternate CD has a more robust installer.**

BUT ... you really do not need to manually install the driver at all. Just install Ubuntu , then install the driver from the repositories.

Save a backup copy of xorg.conf in case this doesn't work.

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.BAK
```

Remove/purge current fglrx and fglrx-amdcccle (If you have used a method outside of aptitude, apt, Software Center or Synaptic, follow the other party's instructions for removal):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

For some users, the fglrx-updates and fglrx-amdcccle-updates packages do not work. If you attempted to install them, also do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

Reboot.

Install the driver:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

Generate a fresh xorg.conf BEFORE REBOOTING!

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

or:

```
sudo amdconfig --initial
```

If you are using multiple AMD graphics cards or AMD dual graphics (i.e.: notebook users), use:

```
sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial
```

or:

```
sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial
```

Reboot again.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI for details.

Comment: I think his problem is that when he boots Ubuntu there's no display :( so he can't do the initial install.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer.

Comment: He wants to install 12.10 which has no alternate image :( Using `nomodeset` may enable him to at least get it installed, press F6 in the "try / install" selection screen, and choose "nomodeset". More here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do. Apologies for the drive-by comments, I'm quite busy but still trying to be helpful :)

Comment: Odd, use the network installer then - http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/12.10/ "The network installer lets you install Ubuntu over the network. This is useful, for example, if you have an old machine with a non-bootable CD-ROM or a computer that can’t run the graphical interface-based installer"

Comment: THIS:

**I think his problem is that when he boots Ubuntu there's no display :( so he can't do the initial install. – roadmr 25 mins ago**

I'll try the network installer when I get a chance.

Comment: @user134349 - that is what the old alternate CD and new network installer is for, more robust installer ;)