# Screen turns black during the installation of Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, uefi

I was following the [UEFI guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) to install Ubuntu on a new computer but after reaching the screen below

[image]

and selecting install, the screen just turns black and nothing happens. I already disabled fast boot, safe boot, Intel SRT, and disabled raid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press F6 to bring up the options menu and turn on "nomodeset". More can be found explained about nomodeset here: [What does `nomodeset` do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add the following boot options? (press e when you see that screen and add):

```
acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux video.use_bios_initial_backlight=0
```

Because, maybe the monitor backlight is turned off.

Comment: I figured it out. Graphics card drivers