# Install hangs after "Starting CUPS printing spooler/server"

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

Laptop's a Clevo d900f/Sager 9280. Successfully installed an older version of Ubuntu a couple years ago, no hardware changes since then. Want more info let me know.

Burnt the "ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso" to a DVD-R. Restarted the laptop, booted from the DVD, welcome page appeared, then the splash-screen with the white/red dots appeared, went to a black screen, then back to the splash-screen, then to a gray screen with a white bar at the top, then to a black screen and remained "hung" for 10 minutes or so until I pressed the power button and was instructed to eject the cd and press any key.

Retried the install but this time I pressed a key at the welcome page and selected English from the advanced welcome page, then selected the option to check the disk. It checked out fine so I retried the install again. Pressed F4 which showed me a list of tasks it was doing. Everything passed except for

```
...
Starting Restore Sound Card State              [fail]
```

but when it got to

```
...
Starting CUPS printing spooler/server              [ OK ]
```

it just "hung" there again for another 10 minutes. I could press the F1-5 buttons to go through the different consoles, type in commands, etc. But I couldn't get back to the splash-screen and I don't know any other keyboard shortcuts or boot options which would show more information.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone might want to delete or close this question as technically it's a duplicate of the second question linked in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the 'nomodeset' parameter via the boot options by pressing F6 from the advanced welcome screen during installation. Apparently not all video cards work correctly with the drivers supplied by the Ubuntu 14.04 package. Enabling that param prevents the loading of the display driver, defaulting instead to BIOS mode. Once the OS is finished installing you can open the Software Updater and choose the driver you want to use.

Related Questions:

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/162075/282706)
[What does `nomodeset` do](https://askubuntu.com/q/207175)