# Ubuntu 14.04 nvidia GTX 960M drivers not working

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I know there are a ton of nvidia driver-related questions, but I tried everything I could find and none worked.

I am using an ASUS ROG GL752VW, core i7 6700HQ, nvidia GTX 960M 4GB GDDR5. I first installed Windows 10 and left ~200GB for my linux OS.

1. Created Ubuntu 14.04 Live-USB with rufus
2. Tried to boot from the live USB. Did not work, had to enable *nomodeset* from the advanced boot options, because it stuck at `Starting CUPS printing spooler/server   [ OK ]` (solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468552/install-hangs-after-starting-cups-printing-spooler-server).
3. After successfully installed, tried installing the drivers
   `apt-get install nvidia-current`

   - After reboot, stuck in a login loop (after inserting correct password, screen would go back to login)
   - Uninstalled the drivers `apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`
4. Tried `add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and installing the newer drivers (latest is 378)

   - Again, same thing happened
   - Uninstalled them once again
5. Tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762831/ubuntu-16-stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-364-drivers), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics/762607#762607), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759641/cant-get-nvidia-drivers-working-with-16-04-logs-out-right-after-login). Nothing worked, same issue.
6. Tried several different drivers (304, 170, 358, 367, 285 and more), with no result.

I also had a GTX 950M laptop and it was working perfectly with nvidia-367 driver.

Could it be a problem with the actual card? If so, has anyone managed to get it working on an UNIX system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Secure Boot was already disabled, I checked that before installing.

Comment: What is your linux architecture? x64 or x86? What linux specificaly are you trying to use? As far as I can see on nvidia site, your GPU is supported only on x86 architecture. Take a look at NVIDIA drivers operating systems list currently supporting your GPU here: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en. As far as I remember I had issues installing Ubuntu on my PC next to Windows. I can't recall what I did to resolve it but I think I checked what specific version of Ubuntu is supporting NVIDIA drivers and it turned out that Ubuntu 15.04 worked for me.

Comment: You installed the wrong drivers. `nvidia-current` install an old extended support driver which is NOT compatible with brand new(ish) hardware like the GTX960M. Also, why 14.04? For your hardware 16.04 or 16.10 has much better support. @jedi - Please delete your comment. It's wrong, misleading and you shouldn't be using outdated releases let alone recommend it.

Comment: @jedi I am using Ubuntu 14.04 x64. As I just checked the nvidia website, the driver 375.39 for Linux x64 supports GTX 960M.

Comment: sudo apt-get cache search nvidia-* Install the latest available. @CelticWarrior, I did not say I recommend using outdated version of Ubuntu. Take it easy, boy. I just gave an example. What's wrong and missleading in my comment in your opinion?

Comment: @CelticWarrior I initially used nvidia-current as it was the first instruction I came up to. But after it did not work, I also tried newer drivers, including the supposedly supported 375.
I originally wanted to install openai gym, and I read some posts about how it has some problems running on 16.04 / 16.10. I will try to do a dist-upgrade and then try installing the drivers again. But as I read on several posts, it will most likely fail to solve this problem.

Comment: @jedi As I said in the OP, I tried installing the latest (which is 378), without any success.

Comment: @jedi 32-bit or 64-bit makes no difference; it may for very old drivers that had 32bit versions only. NOT the case here. GTX960M work with the following versions only: 361, 367, 370, 375 and 378. It's THAT simple. Nowe compare this with your ramblings above. Do you still think is helpful and not misleading? If so you need a serious reality check.

Comment: @Alex The question now is *how* have you installed all those versions and whether or not you purged the installed version before trying a new one.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I did `apt-get remove --purge nvidia*` before installing any new version, then used `apt-get install nvidia-<version>`.

Comment: Really? Aren't you forgetting about the PPA you added (newer versions aren't available at the repositories for 14.04)? So, which one?