# No brightness option in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, brightness

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 I get the brightness option as in normal Ubuntu it should be, but I have a problem that when I start Ubuntu it used to stuck on the starting screen so for that I run
`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` 
and then change
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` 
 to 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`.

After that I am getting no brightness option, nowhere, neither in setting, nowhere. I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473660/brightness-keys-no-longer-work) answer but it didn't work. And I am not able to work on my laptop, the brightness is a painful thing now. 
 So am I the only here with this?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, to adjust the brightness from the terminal, use

```
~$ xbacklight = 75
```

where 75 is the percentage.

Comment: Thanks, that works but I had tried some more changes to grub file and now I am getting the brightness option. But still thanks for the help, it's will be useful.

Comment: @DeepanshuBagotia Can you post your solution, so we can use it which changes are required?