# what exactly do the terms nomodeset, dual boot an wubi mean?

Tags: dual-boot, wubi

I am having this really weird problem of booting my computer(Ubuntu 14.04,which I upgraded to from 12.04 just a day back)since it shows up a black screen every time, after I have chosen my OS(I have XP and Ubuntu ).So I found this site which addresses problems that seem similar.But it has these terms over here which I need some help in understanding.

Comment: Sorry,I its nomodeset.My mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do

Answer (score 1):

No-modeset: [What does `nomodeset` do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do)

Dual-boot means having 2 operating systems on a machine where you, during the -boot- process, select 1 of these to start. Technically it refers to 2 systems but you can have something like 255 operating system on your system (and most would still call this a dual boot).
With this method you will have 1 system active and 1 system dorment.

WUBI is a method of installing Ubuntu -inside- a Windows (but NOT in Windows ME and NOT in Windows 8). You boot into Windows and within Windows you can start Ubuntu. WUBI was created as a tool for people interested in Ubuntu but who did not want to mess with their partitions to get a dual-boot. (so it should not be used as a permanent method for using Ubuntu).

If you want to install Ubuntu inside Windows you can also use virtualBox, VMWare or another "virtual machine" software.