# Upgraded to 14.04 but have a problem editing grub

Tags: bootloader, emacs

I am trying to edit this file to add "nomodeset" to the end of the line.

Is there any way to edit a buffer? Is there a work-around for this?

[image]

Comment: I can tell you what files to edit in what way to make `update-grub` add the `nomodeset` flag to your kernel line every time, if you know how to use an editor. I never used Emacs though and don't know how it relates to your problem.

Comment: emacs is an editor...which editor do you use? yes I'd like help, thanks!

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` Then make your changes and ctrl+x to exit. Then update grub. `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open Ubuntu's configuration file for grub:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/default/grub
  ```
- Edit the content of the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to include the word `nomodeset`
- Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to save the file and exit nano.
- Update the grub boot script to use your new config with `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: this seemed to work. what is it doing exactly?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do