# Persistent Display Issues in Ubuntu 14.04 on Toshiba Satellite L75 B7270

Tags: 14.04, toshiba-satellite, gpu-driver, flicker, i915

At the very top of my screen there is a thin flashing pink line, and all the virtual consoles sport several multi-colored vertical flashing lines, and the console text flickers.

Some specs:

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a Toshiba Satellite L75 B7270. From this url (http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/) I downloaded the image file with this description: “PC (Intel x86) desktop image For almost all PCs. This includes most machines with Intel/AMD/etc type processors and almost all computers that run Microsoft Windows, as well as newer Apple Macintosh systems based on Intel processors. Choose this if you are at all unsure.” I disabled Secure Boot, and switched from UEFI to CSM.

So far I've attempted a few simple suggested remedies with no-to-little luck. I switched from lightdm to gdm. Nada. I tried to use the xrandr command to change the refresh rate, and a refresh rate of 60 is the only available option. I tried using the “Multimedia Systems Selector” to tinker with there Default  Output. No effect. I had I guess what you could call partial success when I booted with nomodeset. The flickering line in my gui was gone and the virtual terminals were fine, but as a commenter noted here ([What does `nomodeset` do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do)), performance takes a hit. Every window I move displays a trail, the windows fade in and out in a weirdly jerky manner, and scrolling text in (for instance) Firefox is jerky and hard on the eyes. This is hardly an ideal “solution.”

Here's the output of some informative commands:

```
$ uname -a
3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:12 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

$ lshw -c video
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller 
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller 
       vendor: Intel Corporation 
       physical id: 2 
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0 
       version: 0b 
       width: 64 bits 
       clock: 33MHz 
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom 
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0 
       resources: irq:61 memory:b0000000-b03fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:4000(size=64)

modinfo i915 (some output omitted)

intree:         Y 
vermagic:       3.13.0-32-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 686 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key 
sig_key:        A7:FC:65:90:FC:4A:8D:85:9A:AE:BD:A2:CA:5D:D0:47:16:24:4F:A0 
sig_hashalgo:   sha512 
parm:           invert_brightness:Invert backlight brightness (-1 force normal, 0 machine defaults, 1 force inversion), please report PCI device ID, subsystem vendor and subsystem device ID to dri-devel@lists.freedesktop.org, if your machine needs it. It will then be included in an upcoming module version. (int) 
parm:           modeset:Use kernel modesetting [KMS] (0=DRM_I915_KMS from .config, 1=on, -1=force vga console preference [default]) (int) 
parm:           fbpercrtc:int 
parm:           panel_ignore_lid:Override lid status (0=autodetect, 1=autodetect disabled [default], -1=force lid closed, -2=force lid open) (int) 
parm:           powersave:Enable powersavings, fbc, downclocking, etc. (default: true) (int) 
parm:           semaphores:Use semaphores for inter-ring sync (default: -1 (use per-chip defaults)) (int) 
parm:           i915_enable_rc6:Enable power-saving render C-state 6. Different stages can be selected via bitmask values (0 = disable; 1 = enable rc6; 2 = enable deep rc6; 4 = enable deepest rc6). For example, 3 would enable rc6 and deep rc6, and 7 would enable everything. default: -1 (use per-chip default) (int) 
parm:           i915_enable_fbc:Enable frame buffer compression for power savings (default: -1 (use per-chip default)) (int) 
parm:           lvds_downclock:Use panel (LVDS/eDP) downclocking for power savings (default: false) (int) 
parm:           lvds_channel_mode:Specify LVDS channel mode (0=probe BIOS [default], 1=single-channel, 2=dual-channel) (int) 
parm:           lvds_use_ssc:Use Spread Spectrum Clock with panels [LVDS/eDP] (default: auto from VBT) (int) 
parm:           vbt_sdvo_panel_type:Override/Ignore selection of SDVO panel mode in the VBT (-2=ignore, -1=auto [default], index in VBT BIOS table) (int) 
parm:           reset:Attempt GPU resets (default: true) (bool) 
parm:           enable_hangcheck:Periodically check GPU activity for detecting hangs. WARNING: Disabling this can cause system wide hangs. (default: true) (bool) 
parm:           i915_enable_ppgtt:Enable PPGTT (default: true) (int) 
parm:           enable_psr:Enable PSR (default: false) (int) 
parm:           preliminary_hw_support:Enable preliminary hardware support. (int) 
parm:           disable_power_well:Disable the power well when possible (default: true) (int) 
parm:           enable_ips:Enable IPS (default: true) (int) 
parm:           fastboot:Try to skip unnecessary mode sets at boot time (default: false) (bool) 
parm:           enable_pc8:Enable support for low power package C states (PC8+) (default: true) (int) 
parm:           pc8_timeout:Number of msecs of idleness required to enter PC8+ (default: 5000) (int) 
parm:           prefault_disable:Disable page prefaulting for pread/pwrite/reloc (default:false). For developers only. (bool) 

$ lspci -v
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) 
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device f931 
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 61 
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M] 
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M] 
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64] 
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled] 
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit- 
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2 
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features 
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I gratefully welcome all advice, and remind those hardcore Linux junkies out there that since my level of knowledge is best described as modest, a bit of explanation may sometimes be required to get your message across.

**
**

I eventually installed the AMD64 version and enabled UEFI. The flickering issue persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a newer kernel fixed this problem. I’ve since moved on to a different computer and didn’t document my solution in detail, but I eventually tried a 3.18 kernel which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr lol

It could be a graphics display adpter/driver issue, I saw similar problems when gnome3 was "new" (and I think Unity was based on or used gnome3?) I'd try a different desktop environment or window manager, try a live usb/cd of Xubuntu or Lubuntu or Kubuntu, or just install xubuntu (xubuntu-desktop or xfce4) or lubuntu (lxde) and boot with xfce or lxde, and see if those help?