# Cannot type disk decryption password during boot

Tags: boot, grub2, password, encryption

The GUI loads to input the decryption password, but when I type, the characters appear in the top-left of my screen, as though I was typing at a console without a command prompt.

Forcing power-off and rebooting allows access to the grub menu, from recovery mode I can type my decryption password without the GUI, and from recovery, I can resume booting.

Comment: Same problem on 15.10, kernel 4.2.0-26

Answer (score 4):

So you don't have to use recovery mode every time:

1. Open a console and type the command

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Look for the line with

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```
3. and change it to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
   ```
4. Then update the grub bootloader with the command

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

*tested using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS*

---

I have ***caused*** the same problem on my own system by using this guide: [Fix low resolution grub and splash screen with Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.binarytides.com/ubuntu-fix-nvidia-graphics/), which says:

1. Edit grub:

   ```
   GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024
   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
   ```
2. and update the bootloader

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Then, create a file (named splash)

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
   ```
4. Fill it with the following line

   ```
   echo FRAMEBUFFER=y
   ```
5. and run the command

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04.1

For those who have the same version of ubuntu I can say that you can fix it by doing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After the next reboot the password field is focussed an you are able to type your password.

*Just performing an usual "sudo apt-get upgrade" will not work!*

Hint: For those who are not familiar with "dist-upgrade": It does not upgrade to the next distribution (i.e. ubuntu 16.10). The difference between these two commands is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

While [@mat](https://askubuntu.com/users/372348/)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/839006/100730) technically worked for my (Kubuntu 17.10) system, it resulted in very poor graphic performance.

The solution that worked better for me was to uncomment the

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

line of `/etc/default/grub`, as it kept the boot splash almost as nice as the *plymouth* one, and more importantly didn't trash my graphic performance.