# Unable to unlock encrypted Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, password, encryption

I checked the encrypted option when I installed Ubuntu 16.04 yesterday just to explore other features. The installation is very fresh.

When I boot my PC it asks for my password to unlock the OS. The problem is that I have no mouse pointer, and I'm not able to type anything. I click tab and it doesn't do anything. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> or <kbd>f2</kbd> I get a black screen but I can't do anything from here. It shows the keyboard is working though.

I can get around this by doing a hard reset. (A hard reset is my only option at this point.) When I do a hard reset from the password screen, the computer boots to GRUB instead of Ubuntu, and then I select Ubuntu from the list, and then it accepts my password just fine and I can log in.

**Can someone please explain to me why this is happening,** and possibly how to fix it? I've installed Gnome Online Accounts, Nvidia video driver 367.44 (which was way too complicated), Firefox ad-ons, and Ubuntu Restricted Extras to get HTML 5 videos to play on YouTube.

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost. 64 bit OS

Comment: Yes, 367.44 should work for that card and it's quite easy to install at System Settings > Software Properties > Additional drivers (tab). That is the driver as tested and packaged by Ubuntu devs. Installing any other way like using the file from Nvidia - the "way too complicated" suggests this is what you did - can result in issues like yours.

Comment: I have an nVidia card and casued the same problem<br>
Just so you don't have to do a hard reset everytime...<br> https://askubuntu.com/questions/709272/cannot-type-disk-decryption-password-during-boot/839006#839006

Comment: I have this exact same problem after i tried to install nvidia drivers. something changed in the bootup meny and the resulution is different at the cryptswap screen and you can't type anything in the box. I have to reboot and startup grub and choose failsafe mode

Comment: please add instructions how to choose or activate `failsafe mode`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to unlock the OS, is this for your encrypted disk or the standard login screen? If you're prompted with something like the screen below, just enter your encryption passphrase.

You're not supposed to see your mouse cursor.

[image]

Comment: I cannot type anything at that screen. I have to hard reset, then it boots to grub instead for some reason, then I choose Ubuntu, and THEN it lets me type.

Comment: Try looking at this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/574296/cannot-enter-password-to-start-ubuntu