# Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS "nosplash" Parameter Causes Major Issues

Tags: 16.04, boot

During boot, the OS would request my password to decrypt my disk but wouldn't detect my input. I tried following this solution: [Cannot enter password to start Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574296/cannot-enter-password-to-start-ubuntu)

The solution essentially has you update boot parameters in `/etc/default/grub` and change `splash` to `nosplash`. After that you can run `update-grub`.

This did solve the issues but it creates a more extreme problem. Once I log in everything is super laggy (e.g. if I type a letter, it takes 10 seconds for the letter to appear).

1. Why is this happening?
2. What can I do to get around this?
3. Before I knew this was the cause, I tried solving this by installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu. Interestingly, unless I selected the following install options I would run into the same problem: 
   [image]

Why in the world would leaving `Encrypt... and/or Use LVM` unchecked cause major lag?

**Additional Information:**

System Hardware: i3-8100 – 8th gen, Ripjaws V 16gb DDR4, Z370 Aorus Gaming 5 chipset, 2x 4TB hard drives, evga 650W

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e91]
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:d000]
    Kernel modules: i915
```