# Removing “splash” = Major Slow Down | 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: boot, grub2

In `/etc/default/grub` when I change `splash` to `nosplash` and run `update-grub`, after a reboot, everything is super laggy (e.g. if I type a letter, it takes 10 seconds for the letter to appear).

And yes, I have already tried reverting back to `splash` to ensure this was the cause.

Why and how do I fix this?

P.s. I need "nosplash" because of this issue:
During boot, the OS would request my password to decrypt my disk but wouldn't detect my input. I tried following this solution: [Cannot enter password to start Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574296/cannot-enter-password-to-start-ubuntu)

Comment: You don't need `nosplash`. Either  use `splash` or remove it. What happens when you remove both `splash` **AND** `nosplash`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I wish that were true.  I tested it on my host today to see if I could duplicate the slowness and without both splash and nosplash my system would not come up to the GUI.  I had to have one or the other there for it to work properly.  Running Xubuntu 16.04.4.

Comment: @Terrance definitely a bug. I'm still on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and have turned off updates since January 1, 2018. I have both `splash` **and** `nosplash` removed in my `/etc/default/grub` and have been running kernel versions 4.14.10 to 4.14.21 successfully over that time. I've just `4.14.23` and will reboot soon. `4.14.22` has mysteriously disappeared. I will report back if there is a problem but, if history is indicative of the future there will not be a problem.

Comment: **Note to "unclear" close voters**: I think the question is clear.

Comment: The question is clear but the title conflicts with the question.  Plus, this question may not be answerable in its present state, and if it is a bug it needs to be reported.

Comment: @user535733 What makes you think I've fixed it? All I've done is gone back to splash but that creates other problems for me. I need to move to nosplash.

Comment: @Terrance Yikes, you're right. Sorry about that. Fixed it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've updated my questions to explain why I need nosplash. And thanks for your help.

Comment: @Terrance I think it is a bug, but I'm relatively new and would appreciate some input here.

Comment: You file bugs here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/  Make sure to read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs on how to file the bug.  I don't run disk encryption and I get two different results on two different systems when it comes to if I have splash / nosplash or none, so I may not be much more help here.