# Installation of Ubuntu: Gets straight to login screen and turns black after login

Tags: boot, login, login-screen, livedvd, usb-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS from a DVD to delete my current Windows 10 System. In the bootmenu after I clicked "Try Ubuntu" the OS leads me straight to the Login Screen. After I entered "Ubuntu" as username and left the password field blank it says:

> The system is running in low-graphics mode
>
> Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected >correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

Later it asks me:

> What would you like to do?
>
> 1. Run in low graphics mode for just one session?
> 2. Reconfigure graphics
> 3. Troubleshoot the error
> 4. Exit to console login

I took the first answer and it showed me a little messagebox after it.

Then after the screen turned black and never reacted again.

I had to restart my PC manually.

I tried it with a Live-USB-Stick too.
But it was even worse because whenever I entered "Try Ubuntu" it leads me straigh to the Login-Screen too but it flashes everytime and I can't use the Login screen to type something in.

I had to restart my PC manually too.

My Specs are:
Windows 10
8GB RAM
NVIDIA GTX 750TI
AMD FX-4100 Quad-Core Processor

Did I burned the DVD wrong and did I mess with the Live-USB up?

(Sorry for grammar and spelling mistakes if you find some of them. English is not my mother tongue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get to this screen

[image]

Once you see this screen, press <kbd>F6</kbd> and you'll see some boot options popping up. Navigate to `nomodeset` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and now choose `Try Ubuntu Without Installing` or `Install Ubuntu`, whichever you want.

You should now see the desktop or installer.

For what is `nomodeset` see [What does `nomodeset` do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do)

Comment: Please press the check mark on the left to sat thanks and help other users identify the corrent answer.