# Keyboard not working with full disk encryption after installing Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, keyboard, encryption, disk

Without the Nvidia drivers I have full resolution and no issues with entering the password. After installing the drivers I see no input and even if I type the password correctly and press enter nothing happens.

After running `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`, I get this:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: CardExpert Technology GK104 [GeForce GTX 770]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: CardExpert Technology GK104 [GeForce GTX 770]
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Comment: Which driver did you install?

Comment: drivers version 367.35. It does not matter which version it is all have the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're having the same issue I am. You get to the disk decrypt stage but you can't type in the password to decrypt the drive. It seems to be related to the fact that the nvidia drivers need access to something on the encrypted disk. I don't have a solution yet but I can tell you if you boot into rescue mode you can enter the password to decrypt the disk and then resume the boot and you'll be able to get into the system. As for what you can do to fix the issue without going through that process, I don't have that answer yet.

Comment: Well, what's worked for me as a workaround is to change: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”` in the `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=””` and then `run sudo grub-update`. It gives me the old style scrolling text login where I have an option to enter my filesystem decryption password.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what is happening. Booting in rescue mode is such an inconvenience. How come there is no fix for this?

Comment: it is `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thanks @bregoSon my brain reversed it. If you want to follow the ticket (or vote for it as affecting you too), https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1386005 or https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1359689

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but resolved it by adding `nomodeset` (what it does [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/207177/512236)) to my boot parameters in grub

Before:

```
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd3,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd3,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd3,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci3,gpt2  e7601194-fd7f-4a39-b686-e1b0e5b29635
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e7601194-fd7f-4a39-b686-e1b0e5b29635
fi
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd  /initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic
```

After:

```
recordfail
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd3,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd3,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd3,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci3,gpt2  e7601194-fd7f-4a39-b686-e1b0e5b29635
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e7601194-fd7f-4a39-b686-e1b0e5b29635
fi
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.15.0-43-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro  quiet splash nomodeset $vt_handoff
initrd  /initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic
```