# How to install ubuntu on macbook pro as a single os?

Tags: boot, macbook, macbook-pro

i want to install ubuntu on macbook pro (early 2011) as **single os** ( **i don't need os x yosemite** ), the hdd in the macbook pro is **new** and have nothing installed on it, i have tried booting from live cd but it won't go beyond option **"try ubuntu"** please help me...!!!

**Resources i have :**
windows 7 and ubuntu (dual booted) laptop,
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS live cd

Answer (score 0):

In order to boot from the DVD on a macbook pro you need to turn off your macbook pro, hold in the option key, turn on the computer while the option key is still in, and let it out when you get a boot menu. Select the DVD as the boot device. Then run Ubuntu setup as normal.

Comment: sir i have tried that already i got the boot menu and selected "try ubuntu" but it wont go beyond that all i get is black screen pls help.

Comment: have you tried "install Ubuntu"?

Comment: yes, the same black screen appears after choosing the option "install ubuntu".

Comment: Are you using 64 bit? A 2011 mac will be using 64 bit.

Comment: if you use 32 bit ISO you will probably get that error

Answer (score 0):

To boot into Ubuntu on the macbook pro you need to add an additional kernel boot option.
In the boot menu where is the option to **"try ubuntu"** press *e* key on your keyboard and add `nomodeset` after `quiet splash`, like this:

```
quiet splash nomodeset
```

Here you can read more about `nomodeset` kernel boot option [What does `nomodeset` do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do)