# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on startup with nvidia 361 drivers

Tags: 16.04

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 and I am trying to install Nvidia drivers for a GTX670.

After installing the Nvidia-361 drivers, the boot process simply freezes with a purple background instead of giving me the decrypt HDD prompt. When using the default xserver drivers the system boots as expected.

However the nvidia drivers work. If I boot into ubuntu in recovery mode, and decrypt the hard drive over the text prompt, and ctrl + c on the options screen it loads me into Ubuntu just fine, I can login using the GUI, my desktop looks as expected and I can even run a game(dota2) without any performance issues.

Q1)What could be the issue here? Any solutions?

Q2)Any method for me to try and debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. What fixed it for was to edit the grub configuration.

In /etc/default/grub change the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line to:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset quiet splash"

then run sudo update-grub

Comment: Adding nomodeset has not made a difference for me. I also did update-grub before reseting.  I did a little bit of reading for what nomodeset does and I saw this following post which states that nomodeset should not have any effect on proprietary drivers. http://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do

Comment: That is strange. I just now reinstalled (for unrelated reasons) and after I installed nvidia proprietary drivers the boot process hung just as you described. I added nomodeset and updated grub and now it works fine again. Don't know what the deal is.