# Ubuntu 16.10 fails to boot in MSI GP72 Laptop

Tags: boot, 16.04, uefi, 16.10, msi

I basically need help figuring out how to get Ubuntu 16.10 AMD64 (Linux 4.8.0-22-generic kernel) to boot the system successfully so that I can go back to actually using it. Booting to 16.04 LTS is also an acceptable solution.

Below you'll find parts with additional information about the system, things I've tried, and the results I got. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. Details ahead :O!

## Summary

I bought this MSI laptop in July this year and, after a *lot* of troubleshooting, I was able to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS AMD64 on it and use it for the last few months without issue. (I have it as a dual-boot system, with Windows 10 on the other side.)

I updated from 16.04 -> 16.10 a few days ago and I cannot get the laptop to boot anymore. Worse, I can't even get it to boot the same 16.04 LTS I had originally from a live USB drive. (Windows still boots, though.) The solutions I had implemented the first time (see below) are *not* making a difference this time around and I have no clue why that's suddenly the case.

Note that the upgrade process appeared to complete normally. I've gone through several similar questions here for previous Ubuntu versions (e.g. 14.04), but they've not worked or are not applicable to my situation. I've spent several days on this already...

---

### Current Behavior and Error Messages

This depends on which boot option I pick, but here's the rundown of trying to boot the current upgraded 16.10 install (boot commands included):

The basic command is `linux /vmlinuz-4.8.0-22-generic root=UUID... ro_quiet splash $vt_handoff`, so I'll only list differences between options for readability.

1. **Default Boot Option:** Command as shown above (with full UUID, of course).

   - System hangs immediately after showing the Ubuntu logo.
   - Hitting a key to show the console before the hang shows that no messages are ever written to it.
2. **Pre-Upgrade Boot Command:** Added `acpi_osi="Linux" pci=nomsi` arguments.

   - Same behavior as above
   - These arguments were part of the solution to get it to work back in July with a 16.04 install.
3. **Recovery Mode 1:** This adds the `ro recovery nomodeset` kernel arguments

   - Lots of output showing services getting started
   - Last message is the `[OK] Started Light Display Manager.` (i.e. the `lightdm` service)
   - Screen goes black here and no longer responds.
   - Only error message displayed is below.
4. **Recovery Mode 2:** Same recovery arguments as #3, but with `acpi_osi="Linux" pci=nomsi` manually added

   - Basically same result as #3

The only error I see logged in options 3 and 4 is:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
See 'systemctl status nvidia-percistenced.service' for details
```

The boot process does *not* hang on this failure. The boot process continues until after the LightDM service has started, but before you actually see the greeter.

Also, I'd try the `systemctl` command, but:

1. hung systems don't accept commands, and
2. I had actually purged the `nvidia-367` drivers/package during a previous recovery attempt (`apt-get purge nvidia\*`) in favor of a more recent version from the official page.

In any case, even if the driver were the problem (e.g. can't be loaded as a LKM), I'd (at most) expect the greeter and graphical UI to *not* show up, in which case, I'd have the terminal to log in and solve it. However, I can't get that far.

### Prior Troubleshooting Attempts and Results

Since I've seen (and solved) some of these errors before, I spent the last few days trying to go through the steps and solve the problem before posting here. Unfortunately, things that have worked before for similar-looking problems are (AFAIK) not helping.

#### Originally Successful Solution (not working this time around)

When I troubleshooted back in July, these are the things I did that helped me solve the boot and login problems I had:

1. Add the `acpi_osi="Linux"` kernel argument to workaround ACPI table bugs

   - These are generally built for Windows systems by BIOS, and can cause problems on Linux.
2. Add the `pci=nomsi`  kernel argument to workaround issue with this laptop

   - Without this option, the kernel would keep logging a message *ad-infinitum* and eat away available space in the partition, and this option fixed that problem.
3. Disable Secure Boot to allow log in after driver installation

   - Basically, I cannot use the Nouveau driver for a project I'm working on. I need to use the NVIDIA driver, which is not signed (it builds locally during installation) and, in the secure boot world, is an untrusted kernel module.
   - In a Secure Boot environment, *unsigned* kernel modules cannot are not allowed to load/work as you might expect, and building/installing NVIDIA drivers lets the login screen show up, but every login attempt will fail before it you get to your desktop (it falls back right into the login screen).
   - You have to disable Secure Boot to get past this point (or find a way for Microsoft to sign your custom-built driver (good luck), or do it yourself (good luck again)...

I've tried these things this time around for my 16.10 re-install, but I've not seen the same results. The mystery is that I can't even get 16.04, which worked in July, to behave the same way now as it did back then. I have no explanation for this.

I had also used `pci=off` on a previous HP laptop to work around boot issues, but trying that with the MSI got me nowhere.

#### Booting from Live USB Fails

Right now, trying to boot 16.04 LTS or 16.10 from a live USB, with default options¹, hangs with the following messages in the console:

```
...
lvm2-monitor.service
tmp.mount
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
resolvconf.service
[ kernel-time] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: pci: failed to adjust lnkctl speed
[ kernel-time] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsuported splx structure
[ kernel-time] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 22s! [plymouthd:314]
[ kernel-time] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 23s! [plymouthd:314]
[ kernel-time] ...<same message>...
[ kernel-time] INFO: task systemd:1 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ kernel-time]       Tainted: G             L 4.8.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu
...
[ kernel-time] INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
[ kernel-time] NMI watchdog: ...<same message>...
```

Adding the `acpi_osi="Linux" pci=nomsi` to the live USB command produces slightly different output, with the added error line about `pci_enable_msi failed - -22`

```
...
lvm2-monitor.service
tmp.mount
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
systemd-update-utmp.service
[ kernel-time] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: pci: failed to adjust lnkctl speed
[ kernel-time] pci_enable_msi failed - -22
[ kernel-time] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Unsuported splx structure
[ kernel-time] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 23s! [plymouthd:314]
[ kernel-time] INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
```

I've seen the soft lockup messages before (in HP laptops) and I could *always* trace them back to the VT-d and CPU Virtualization options being *disabled* in the BIOS, and enabling them would quickly resolve that issue. While I don't immediately remember if I had these CPU stalls back in July, if I did, then I would've solved them the same way. (You still need virtualization if you want to run virtual machines anyway -e.g. virtual box.)

I read other answers around the site, some of which suggested *disabling* CPU C states, but that did *not* work for me either.

---

### Relevant BIOS Settings

Here're the settings that have been relevant before, per tab, and their *current* values, which were working prior to the 16.04 -> 16.10 upgrade. Note that I've tried different enabled/disabled combinations among some of the options (e.g. disabling hyper-threading, c states, etc) already, without success.

#### Advanced Tab

1. **Intel Virtualization Technology:** Enabled
2. **VT-d:** Enabled
3. **Hyper-threading:** Enabled
4. **CPU C states:** Enabled

#### Boot Tab

1. **Fast Boot:** Enabled
2. **Boot mode select:** UEFI

#### Security Tab -> Secure Boot Menu

1. **Secure Boot:** Disabled
2. **Secure Boot Mode:** Standard

---

### Footnotes

1. Default boot command in live USB: `linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash ---`

Comment: Hi @ray, the details on your question shows that you took some time to research the problem however, that might work to your disadvantage as this question question is too long(in my humble opinion anyway) , cant you possibly make it smaller? A question this long might put off some people unfortunately. That is just my opinion.

Comment: @TshilidziMudau Déjà vu. Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, no, none. Why?,  you ask. Because I didn't read that whole question because it is way too long and i can tell you, i am not the only one who wont read the question because it is too long. Maybe I'm wrong, I guess only time will tell. I would suggest you summarize your question. That way we wont have to read too many paragraphs before we finally find out what the problem you are facing is. have a look here to see what makes a good question : http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TshilidziMudau Well, I appreciate the thought. The post has had a summary with the question itself from the get-go with a big "summary" header and broken down into parts. The later parts were explicitly only the additional details (i.e. things I think I'd be asked about had they not been mentioned, etc). In any case, thanks for the input. I moved a few things around to try and make some things more clear.

Comment: cool, you are welcome buddy.

Comment: I have no specific solution, but it looks like you may be having a problem with the video drivers. You might try removing the `quiet splash` options from the boot options to get more verbose output, which may provide a clue. You could also try hitting Ctrl+Alt+F2 after booting (or after it *would normally* finish). If you're lucky, this will get you a text-mode console you can use for debugging.

Comment: @RodSmith The system was fully hung, so there was no way to get to the alternate terminals. I did post my solution, but can't accept it yet.

Comment: Great! I've upvoted your answer so that others can refer to this as a duplicate, should the same problem/question crop up in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem shortly after posting the question, though I wanted to be sure before trying to post my answer. Note that *no* additional modifications to BIOS/UEFI settings were needed -aside from what I had already specified in the OP.

---

#### My Steps to Fix

The process was basically as follows:

1. Add kernel arguments: `nomodeset acpi_osi=` to allow boot to proceed

   - Using `acpi_osi="Linux"` didn't work at first; it had to be empty as shown above¹
   - You can edit the boot commands by pressing <kbd>e</kbd> in the GRUB menu
2. This allows a successful boot of 16.10 from the live USB.

   - In my case, I went for a re-install²
3. After re-installing, I changed the kernel arguments back to `pci=nomsi acpi_osi="Linux"`

I'm not sure why `nomodeset`³ is necessary to get the system to boot *at first*, but not really necessary *after the fact*, which is probably why I forgot that I had probably done this back in July when I troubleshooted my original 16.04 LTS install. In any case, I hope this helps anyone else that might come across similar issues.

---

#### Making Changes Permanent

Currently, you have to edit the boot command every time, and that gets old fast. To update the boot command *permanently*, follow these steps:

1. Open `/etc/default/grub` for editing, as `root`

   - `sudo vim /etc/default/grub` from the terminal
   - Change `vim` for your favorite editor (e.g. `nano`)
2. Edit this line as follows and save the changes

   - **Default:** `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`
   - **Edited:** `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pci=nomsi acpi_osi=\"Linux\""`
3. Run the `sudo update-grub2` command to generate an updated `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file

   - Remember to ***not*** edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` directly

If you're wondering about the `pci=nomsi` argument, this prevents the kernel from filling up your drive (i.e. `/var/log/syslog`) with lots of bogus messages. This seems specific to the MSI laptop, as my desktop and a former HP laptop didn't need this workaround.

---

#### Footnotes

1. If you don't change `acpi_osi=` back to `acpi_osi="Linux"`, and you've installed the `nvidia` drivers package, login attempts will fail and you will see the greeter re-displayed. You can identify this because your password is correct (i.e. no error message about password mismatch) and, if you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> into a terminal, you can log in successfully from there.
2. If you have your `/home` directory in its own partition (as you should, IMHO), then you just make sure to mark the partition for use with the same file system (e.g. ext4) and mount point (i.e. `/home`), but *without* formatting it. I also re-entered the same account credentials during installation. Note that old accounts will still be in your `/home` directory, but may not show up if you use Settings >> Users, since that reads from `/etc/passwd`. You may need to `sudo adduser ...` to get them to show up correctly.
3. See [What does `nomodeset` do?](https://askubuntu.com/a/207177/535457)

Comment: I can confirm the above fix works on MSI GP72 6QF in either Ubuntu 16.04 (Linux Mint actually) with the latest kernel, or Ubuntu 16.10.  The caveat is, this only works for me with the proprietary NVidia driver.  I cannot get any solution to work on this machine with nouveau through the integrated Intel GPU.  With nouveau, only _nomodeset_ (with acpi_osi= pci=nomsi) works, which forces software rendering.

Answer (score 2):

I have same laptop, GP72-6qf .. have Ubuntu running on it now.

1. Make sure you have the latest Bios and firmware updates. there was a new release in October.
2. Set **CPU C states**: Disabled & **Fast Boot**: Disabled
3. Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` and change

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi= acpi_backlight=none acpi=ht pci=nomsi"
   ```

   Then run `sudo update-grub`
4. Update Ubuntu (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`).

Comment: CPU C States to disabled is what got me to finally boot to the grub menu (and actually boot at all again) after i installed the nvidia-current (which is old) drivers and got the black screen problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I was having problems to get Nvidia Drivers to run on Ubuntu 16.04

My Fix:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
apt-get update
apt-get install nvidia-375
reboot
```