# How to get nvidia-persistenced daemon to work properly?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-prime

I have some graphical issues on login when I'm using the intel gpu.
I checked the boot logs and it shows that the nvidia persistence service failed to load on the intel gpu. After running `systemctl status nvidia-persistenced.service` I found that nvidia-persistenced tries to run the following command `/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --user nvidia-persistenced --no-persistence-mode --verbose` but /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced doesn't exist.

Does anyone know how to get nvidia-persistenced to run properly?

Comment: I have the same problem. If I boot on the intel GPU driver, nvidia-persistenced fails to boot. Also, if I try rebooting afterwards, the reboot process hangs and doesn't complete. However, if I boot on the nvidia GPU driver, I encounter none of the problems  I mentioned.

Comment: I tried several things and nothing works. I can get nvidia-persistenced running but when nvidia-persistenced works I can't start the nvidia gpu (it just crashes). Might be a problem with the kernel. I'm using 4.8 because it supports skylake but a lot of problems started to occur after upgrading. If I ever find a solution I'll post it here.

Comment: Much appreciated. Kernel 4.4 doesn't support skylake ?

Comment: it does but just barely. For example a lot of power saving options don't work on 4.4 with a skylake processor.

Comment: I'm using 4.4 right now. Do you suggest upgrading to a more recent kernel ?

Comment: If you are using a skylake processor then yes. 4.8 supports skylake much better and (I don't know if this is true but) it is claimed that 4.8 improves the life expectancy of the processor due to reduced stress. The newer kernal should allow your processor to reach a deeper power saving state (4.4 only goes to PC3 and 4.8 goes to PC8) which improves battery life.

Comment: Ok. You said earlier upgrading to 4.8 caused a lot of problems. What kind of issues do you encounter ?

Comment: my intel graphics driver was changed from intel to gallium which has problems with turning the screen back on after a suspend and a lot of other stuff. Took me a while to discover that but not very difficult to fix. I also had some missing modules from intel but that was fixable using intel's own website. besides that I only had some minor bugs that have been resolved by now.

Comment: I tried 4.8 and it broke my UI. I couldn't start anything graphic, I just had a tty (hopefully). For now, I uninstalled persistenced, and I switch to the nvidia driver before I shutdown my computer. I will wait until kernel 4.8 is backported to Ubuntu 16.04. But you can still post here if you have any news. Thanks !

Comment: if it doesn't work you can always switch back to your old kernel. try booting with `nomodeset` and fix all the graphic driver problems before trying to login (for example by reinstalling them)

Comment: oke.....I just fixed it (sort of) I formatted my disk and installed ubuntu 16.10. Afterwards I installed nvidia-367 (not 370) and everything works now (except suspend on intel graphics).

Comment: Does `grep "FAIL" /var/log/boot.log` return _**[FAILED]** Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon._? Might be relatet [with this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838212/ubuntu-16-10-fails-to-boot-in-msi-gp72-laptop). I have `nvidia-persistenced` under `/usr/lib/nvidia-375/bin/`.

Comment: Might be related with [this Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-persistenced/+bug/1693123).

Comment: Ooh man, this is half a year ago. Everything works nowadays. besides isn't your bug nvidia 375 specific?

Comment: @Akisame I see you got it working. It might have to do with installing the adequate device driver. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

At least for `nvidia-375==375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-375/bin/nvidia-persistenced /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced
```

looks like enough.

Please mark this bug as affecting you too: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-persistenced/+bug/1693123

Comment: But `prime-select intel` deletes `/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced`

Comment: `sudo systemctl mask nvidia-persistenced.service` it is for now.

Answer (score 2):

The [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/942250/130026) is essentially correct, but it didn't work for me. Main problem is that `nvidia-xxx` drivers are not simply better with increasing `xxx`; they also correspond do different card models. [Here's the list of all available drivers](https://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html). You'll have to check out your card model before you install, or it simply does not work.
You can find that out [with `lspci`](https://askubuntu.com/a/72774/130026), which lists all devices connected to the PCI bus:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G92 [GeForce GTS 250] (rev a2)
```

With my GeForce GTS250, [I need to use the 340 driver](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/). You will need to check out your card in that list, and install the appropriate driver.