# NVIDIA Persistence Daemon Fails, symlinks are delted

Tags: 16.04, drivers, unity, nvidia-prime

System:
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS - Unity Desktop fresh install
Dell XPS 9650 Intel 7700 HQ + Nvidia 1050 GTX mobile

I'm trying to get Nvidia drivers (415) + Cuda + prime select to run on my work Notebook. But every time the Intel graphicscard is selected, all symlinks are destroyed:

```
ng@dw10048-ubuntu ~ ls -al /usr/bin/nvidia-*                                                                     
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     52 Nov 18 08:22 /usr/bin/nvidia-bug-report.sh -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_bug_report
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     58 Nov 18 08:22 /usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-cuda-mps-control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     57 Nov 18 08:22 /usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-server -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-cuda-mps-server
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     51 Nov 18 08:22 /usr/bin/nvidia-debugdump -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-debugdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    270 Jan 30  2018 /usr/bin/nvidia-detector
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     54 Nov 18 08:22 /usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_persistenced
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 224600 Nov 13 15:33 /usr/bin/nvidia-settings
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     45 Nov 18 08:22 /usr/bin/nvidia-smi -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_smi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     49 Nov 18 08:22 /usr/bin/nvidia-xconfig -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_xconfig

 ng@dw10048-ubuntu ~ ls -al /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_app_profile -> /usr/share/nvidia-415/nvidia-application-profiles-415.13-rc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 74 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_app_profile_keys -> /usr/share/nvidia-415/nvidia-application-profiles-415.13-key-documentation
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_bug_report -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/bin/nvidia-bug-report.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-cuda-mps-control -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 56 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-cuda-mps-control.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/alt-nvidia-415-cuda-mps-control.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-cuda-mps-server -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-server
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-debugdump -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/bin/nvidia-debugdump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_drv -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_modconf -> /lib/nvidia-415/modprobe.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_persistenced -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/bin/nvidia-persistenced
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_smi -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/bin/nvidia-smi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-smi.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/alt-nvidia-415-smi.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Nov 18 08:22 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_xconfig -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/bin/nvidia-xconfig

 ng@dw10048-ubuntu ~ sudo prime-select intel                                                                      
Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['nvidia-415', 'nvidia-415']
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['nvidia-415', 'nvidia-415']
Info: selecting nvidia-415-prime for the intel profile
update-alternatives: /usr/lib/nvidia-415-prime/ld.so.conf wird verwendet, um /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) im manuellen Modus bereitzustellen
update-alternatives: /usr/lib/nvidia-415-prime/ld.so.conf wird verwendet, um /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf) im manuellen Modus bereitzustellen
update-alternatives: /usr/lib/nvidia-415-prime/alt_ld.so.conf wird verwendet, um /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) im manuellen Modus bereitzustellen
update-alternatives: /usr/lib/nvidia-415-prime/alt_ld.so.conf wird verwendet, um /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf) im manuellen Modus bereitzustellen

 ng@dw10048-ubuntu ~ ls -al /usr/bin/nvidia-*                         
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     52 Nov 18 08:22 /usr/bin/nvidia-bug-report.sh -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_bug_report
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     51 Nov 18 08:22 /usr/bin/nvidia-debugdump -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-debugdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    270 Jan 30  2018 /usr/bin/nvidia-detector
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 224600 Nov 13 15:33 /usr/bin/nvidia-settings
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     45 Nov 18 08:22 /usr/bin/nvidia-smi -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_smi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     49 Nov 18 08:22 /usr/bin/nvidia-xconfig -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_xconfig

 ng@dw10048-ubuntu ~ ls -al /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 59 Nov 18 08:25 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_app_profile -> /usr/share/nvidia-415/nvidia-application-profiles-415.13-rc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 74 Nov 18 08:25 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_app_profile_keys -> /usr/share/nvidia-415/nvidia-application-profiles-415.13-key-documentation
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Nov 18 08:25 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_bug_report -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/bin/nvidia-bug-report.sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Nov 18 08:25 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-debugdump -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/bin/nvidia-debugdump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov 18 08:25 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_modconf -> /lib/nvidia-415/modprobe.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Nov 18 08:25 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_smi -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/bin/nvidia-smi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Nov 18 08:25 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-smi.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/alt-nvidia-415-smi.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Nov 18 08:25 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_xconfig -> /usr/lib/nvidia-415/bin/nvidia-xconfig
```

I've read:

[Ubuntu 18.04 boot stuck at message “Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon” after installing nVidia 390.74](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060893/ubuntu-18-04-boot-stuck-at-message-started-nvidia-persistence-daemon-after-ins)

[Ubuntu 17.10 boot stuck at message "Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon" after installing nVidia 384.90](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973605/ubuntu-17-10-boot-stuck-at-message-started-nvidia-persistence-daemon-after-ins)

[How to get nvidia-persistenced daemon to work properly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845113/how-to-get-nvidia-persistenced-daemon-to-work-properly)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-persistenced/+bug/1693123

But there only seems to be to two valid solutions:

- Don't use Unity + GDM -> which I can't do, since we still deliver Software for 16.04 LTS, which needs to be tested in Unity
- Use Nouveau or Intel drivers -> which isn't what i want to do since I want to use CUDA

So unless anyone knows something better I would create an alias which calls a wrapper script recreating all symlinks after switching.

Also does anybody know what the root cause of this problem is. Why are the symlinks delted?