# How do you install Ubuntu on an MSI Prestige PE60-6QE Laptop?

Tags: msi

How could you possibly install Ubuntu on a MSI Prestige Laptop?, mine has some problems also when booting on Ubuntu, it freezes right after it starts loading the Ubuntu Logo, i had tried legacy and csm with legacy, but it still isn't working correctly, and also, does ubuntu work on a Realtek HD Sound Card? thanks for replying
-EDIT-

And my Graphics Card is Nvidia Geforce 960M, Processor is Intel HQ6700 i7 Skylake Processor, so does ubuntu support the recent Intel Skylake Processors?

~Martin Josef

Comment: Two other threads with similar systems: Failing to Boot Ubuntu 16.10 in MSI GP72
http://askubuntu.com/questions/838212/failing-to-boot-ubuntu-16-10-in-msi-gp72
[SOLVED] MSI GT72S 6QE - Freezes on boot unless acpi=off is used
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303544

Answer (score 2):

I have a MSI GE62 with i7-6700 Skylake and Nvidia GTX970M, and It finally works with ubuntu 16.04 so here are the different steps:

1. **BIOS:** Enter the Bios by pressing the <kbd>delete</kbd> key.
   Choose UEFI-disable Secureboot and disable Fastboot(for Fastboot maybe its not obligatory)
   By installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: type the <kbd>e</kbd> key to access the Grub and it must look like that:
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`
2. Now Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed you must change the GRUB:
   Please type in the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) :
   `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Then you will see a text editor that will open with the grub configuration file. I changed mine and my Grub configuration file looks like this :

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"
# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

3. now type: `sudo update-grub`
4. update your kernel:

   `sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa`
   `sudo apt-get update`
   `sudo apt-get install ukuu`
5. Restart your computer by typing: `sudo reboot`
   Please note the only line I changed in the Grub configuration file is this one: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1"`
6. Please also note it may take a few reboots with some updates of Ubuntu so that your computer can be turned on and turned off normally