# Can't find where my windows 10 partition is after having installed ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I've got an MSI GE62 Apache Pro. It came with FreeDOS, and I installed Windows 10 in Legacy (not UEFI) mode. Then, I wanted to install Ubuntu 16 Server and, when I made the partition into my solid disk and installed grub, but grub only recognize Ubuntu. I've tried using Boot Repair, but it failed.

Maybe I've broken something, but I don't know how to see if I still have Windows 10 somewhere, how to make grub find it or what to do up to this point. Any hint? I've search a lot in the Internet and still don't know how to start Windows again.

Here is my lsblk:

```
NAME                     FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                                  238,5G            
├─sda1                   ext2          487M /boot      
├─sda2                                   1K            
└─sda5                   LVM2_member   238G            
  ├─PuppedToy--vg-root   ext4         77,3G /          
  └─PuppedToy--vg-swap_1 swap         15,9G [SWAP]     
sdb                                  931,5G            
└─sdb1                   ntfs        931,5G            New Volume
sr0                                   1024M
```

If i have destroyed Windows 10, how can I reinstall it? Thank you. As you can see, I'm pretty new with this.

EDIT:

Here is the paste from boot repair http://paste2.org/GbnbfzN7

I have an extra problem: after Boot Repair, grub doesn't show any option. I can't even boot from USB.

Comment: You have "destroyed" it by selecting encryption, which in turn took over the whole drive. You can't recover it. At best, you may use some tools (software) to recover **files** but the chances now are really slim and they decrease the longer you use as it is now.

Comment: Another slightly different model, but issues are often common by brand. http://askubuntu.com/questions/838212/ubuntu-16-10-fails-to-boot-in-msi-gp72-laptop

Comment: forget about recovery,,I know that pain. get over it

Answer (score 1):

I see two storage devices on your system, shown as sda and sdb.

As is apparent in following lines of your boot repair report (lines no. 180 and 181) there is no OS installed on sdb.

```
sda : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    has-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sdb : not-GPT,  BIOSboot-not-needed,    has-no-EFIpart,     not-usb,    no-os,  2048 sectors * 512 bytes
```

Based on the result of `lsblk` you shared, you have formatted whole of your sba while installation of Ubuntu and therefor your Windows files and partitions are gone.

For doing any recovery, if you want to simply get back your windows, there is no chance for it and you should install again. But if you want to get back your data, you should go for data recovery process which I don't think you would get anything useful from it (since your disk is formatted and new data is rewritten on it.

If you didn't have very important data on it forget about recovery. Otherwise, just turn off your system to prevent more damage to your data and go through a deep data recovery.