# boot-repair Messed up MSI laptop boot time

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a msi GE62vr laptop that I installed windows 10 when I bought it (it was freedos). After a while I decided to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as dual boot on the HDD (Windows is on SSD).

Everything went perfectly but there was a slight problem, grub was not showing in boot and computer was directly booting into Windows. Not much a big deal, I started looking for solutions.

**First:** I installed boot-repair when I am in Ubuntu (Used Windows 10 advanced startup to get access inside Ubuntu), I activated **recommended repair** button, **which immediately messed up the startup.** The computer that used to boot up in **10 seconds** is now booting up in at least **7-8 minutes**. And it still directly booted into Windows.

**Second:** Then I did what suggested here:

https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/

I know the problem description here does not match my issue, but this solution helped me before in a similar problem so I used it again, now the computer boots into GRUB(original problem solved), however the boot slowing caused `boot-repair` still persists and I don't have slightest clue how to reverse the process.

Any ideas appreciated.

**Edit1:** Here is the information from the `boot-repair` software if it helps.

https://pastebin.com/bTJftnKE

**Edit2:** I will consider using Windows System Recovery if no solution emerges. ( I did not check if a recovery point created recently.)

Comment: You have both installed in UEFI boot mode. And should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12, check manual. Similar systems may have same issues: http://askubuntu.com/questions/838212/failing-to-boot-ubuntu-16-10-in-msi-gp72 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303544 & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2296878

Comment: @oldfred please post that as an answe.

Comment: If Rockybilly says one of the links worked then I will post details. LInks are just to other threads with MSI systems that may have similar issues as often common by brand & similar model.

Comment: Your Boot Repair output is truncated -- I see only 79 lines, which leaves out a great deal of potentially important information. Please see if you can post the rest of the output. Also, please clarify *which OS* is slow to boot -- Windows (which is how I'm reading the question), Ubuntu, or both; and is there a difference in boot speed depending on which OS was previously booted?

Comment: @RodSmith The slowness was before the GRUB appearance, so with the MSI amblem, before the operating system had selected. OS's had opened without any problem after that.

Comment: New UEFI systems have a fast boot setting. That is different than Windows fast start up. UEFI fast boot assumes that system has no changes/reconfiguration and data previously written to drive is still correct & it then immediately starts booting. Issue is that you have no time to press any key even to get back into UEFI. And assumption is that you can get back into UEFI from Windows. But if Windows is broken then bigger issue. Most will do a normal boot from total cold boot or power down, which if laptop is also difficult as you must also remove battery.

Comment: Enabling and disabling fast boot in BIOS did not resolve the problem. It was the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I ran these commands and the problem solved, I don't know why.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-pc linux-generic
```

Comment: Although your Boot Repair output is truncated, it's clear that you're booting in EFI mode, so installing `grub-pc` should not be necessary, and in fact could create problems down the road. My hunch is that your `grub.cfg` file was bad, and installing the packages you've specified forced `grub.cfg` to be re-written; but I can't be sure of that without seeing more information, and maybe I could never be sure of it, given that the old configuration is now gone.