# Unable to boot Ubuntu Live CD 16.04-2

Tags: boot, nvidia, uefi

I have the following config:
Intel Pentium g4400
Nvidia gtx 1070
4 GB DDR4 RAM
160 GB HDD
UEFI

I tried installing cleanly as well as alongside windows 10 but the same problem persists.

After selecting any of the 4 options (viz. Install/Run/Check for defects) the screen shows the following error messages:
Failed to train: Aborting dp
CPU Stuck for 22s

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Try burning the iso to a usb. And also I recommend you to clean your disk before you do it. Beware though, if you have import stuff already on your partition/disk move all of them to some other external hard drive or on the cloud. if dual booting, just do a clean of that partition in which you will install ubuntu. Next I recommend you to install ubuntu using custom. If your installing aside windows 10, there may be some problems. If there still is the error message please pm me and I'll try to find another problem

Comment: I burnt it on 2 usb drives and faced the same problem

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/838212/ubuntu-16-10-fails-to-boot-in-msi-gp72-laptop