# Ubuntu does not recognize SSD during installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

Please, someone could help me? I need my computer for Dual Boot so I can work with development with my embedded system. VMWARE does not work with Nvidia Jetson TX2.

I downloaded an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) for 64-bit PC AMD64 image.
From [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/). (Ubuntu website)

I am trying to install on my SSD on my MSI Aegis Ti3 computer. It has Intel i7-7700k, 2 Samsung SSD M2 in RAID, 1 HDD, 1 Samsung SSD connected by SATA.

The BIOS is custom made for the Aegis Ti3 computer, so as the motherboard.

My problem is that when I go into the installation of the Ubuntu the only storage drive recognized is the USB drive that I use.

I checked online some people claiming about the AHCI controller for the SSD, but I already configured that over my SSD drive.

The computer is new, I just got it out of the box.

In order to boot into linux I had to add the following to the kernel  “**nomodeset**” and “**libata.force=noncq**“.

I would like to know better what is going wrong, and how to fix it.

I looked for help in the following tutorials:

Installing Ubuntu 14.04.3 + Windows 8.1 (Dual-boot) on MSI GE72 2QD Apache
https://www.ricston.com/blog/installing-ubuntu-14-04-3-windows-8-1-dual-boot-msi-ge72-2qd-apache/

Universal USB Installer – Easy as 1 2 3

Install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1 in 10 easy steps

I also had problems creating a backup image for my Windows 10 because of the Journal. But that is another story.

Detail: my windows must but in RAID, because I have 2 M2 SSD merged together. My Ubuntu must boot in AHCI.

Comment: Do not know if this helps. Also MSI and often issues are similar across models: https://askubuntu.com/questions/838212/ubuntu-16-10-fails-to-boot-in-msi-gp72-laptop & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303544 & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297815

Comment: The notebooks have a lot of trouble with Linux. Fortunately I had far less problems, if I had a 10gb pen-drive I would be able to easily install Ubuntu. It just not locate my other hard-drives because this motherboard should have some crazy configuration that don`t let me see the other devices in AHCI when my SSD in RAID is with configured to boot windows. I called MSI support and they told me that they do not provide support for Linux and if the intention is not gaming they will not be helpful. It just happens that gaming computers are cheaper than engineering workstations and as good as.

Comment: Best to never mention Linux to first level support of any vendor. Script is to automatically say they do not support Linux. They just do not want to get into specific issues. Is RAID level RAID 0. That is more for gaming but not for general use as any drive failure destroys all data. If RAID 1, you often can just break RAID. But if RAID 0 and you turn off RAID, half of data is on one drive and half on other drive.  Backup & total restore then required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have two drives configured in a bios fake raid.  If you must dual boot with windows, then your only hope is for the `dmraid` package to recognize the fakeraid under linux.  This should "work" though fakeraid does not actually handle failures correctly so if you are using it for anything other than raid0, you are in for a bad surprise when things to pear shaped since those levels imply redundancy and should tolerate failure.  If you are OK with that failure, then again, it should "work".  Run `sudo dmraid -n` and add its output to your question for more information.

Comment: I am afraid MSI is using RAID 0. I consider

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i consider it slighty risky. I am afraid MSI is using RAID 0 and crash the whole system. I consider trying to think about other options. It still does not explain why I cannot locate my SSD that is in non RAID. If I cannot install in my SSD I may consider expand my M2 SSD and change it to non-RAID. It might work, I don`t know. What I don`t like is that I need Ubuntu so badly to work with my Nvidia Jetson TX2 and other embedded  systems.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to psusi's point, which is valid, you may be running into driver problems. Sometimes hardware is not recognized by Ubuntu because it's too new. In cases like this, the only solution is to use a newer kernel, or at least a new(er) kernel module. The easiest way to do this in Ubuntu is to use a newer version of Ubuntu. Right now, that means Ubuntu 17.04, or even a 17.10 pre-release. (I'm not sure what sort of state 17.10 is in, though -- it won't be released for almost four months, so it may not be even remotely ready for use.)

Comment: I wish, but I am tied to Jetson TX2. https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetpack requirement is kernel 4.4 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I guess I will have to increase my skill with VMWARE until I get more memory to operate without RAID. It will be interesting having 4-5 storage units. my pen-drives will start to be assigned letter Z:  .I still have hope in finding an alternative solution in this mean time. I really cant understand how MSI made the hardware complicate something as simple as getting Linux.