# MSI GS63vr won't boot after installation

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, msi

I have the MSI GS63vr and when I load the Ubuntu live usb and install it, everything goes perfect until it's time to restart.

1. The laptop wont restart on it's own from the Ubuntu screen and
2. When I manually restart it, the laptop will either stay stuck on the purple screen or the black screen where it claims that the CPU 3 or 4 was stuck for 22s.

I have reinstalled it many times now and went through many forms and still nothing seems to work. I get the grub2 screen but then it freezes after that.

Comment: Please share Ubuntu version details.

Comment: Please [edit] and post informations such as requested above and also your hardware specifications, namely graphics.

Comment: This might help [Ubuntu login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: different models, but issues are often common by brand: Failing to Boot Ubuntu 16.10 in MSI GP72
http://askubuntu.com/questions/838212/failing-to-boot-ubuntu-16-10-in-msi-gp72
[SOLVED] MSI GT72S 6QE - Freezes on boot unless acpi=off is used
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303544

Answer (score 1):

After finishing the installation of your new OS [Ubuntu] you should wait 2 minutes before pressing restart.

It will freeze anyways but it will help grub finish.

After it freezes you need to force the shut down of your computer, turn it on and press the left shift multiple times while the Laptop is restarting.

This will get you in the Ubuntu safe mode, Press the "e" key and you need to add `nouveau.modeset=0`

you will  find this code `splash $vt_handoff`, what you need to do is add the `nouveau.modeset=0` (Use the arrows of the keyboard to move)

It should look like this `[splash $vt_handoff nouveau.modeset=0]` then you need to press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save changes and restart.

I will leave a picture to help you spot the code where you need to add the `nouveau.modeset=0`.

[image]