# I cannot install Ubuntu on MSI GL62 6QD

Tags: system-installation, msi

I cannot install Ubuntu to MSI GL62 6QD. I tried Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and Ubuntu 17.10 but both of them stuck at the following screen.

[image]

I also tried to boot in legacy and UEFI (when Fast boot is disabled).

Comment: There is nothing for us to answer ... you probably need to google about this machine, its videocard and see if people posting tips on it. Try different kernel parameters at the grub screen: acpi off, nomodeset, and check the installer if it has the correct hash.

Comment: Often issues are common across models by vendor, so even though different model solutions may work for you. Best to only use UEFI. MSi GT72VR-6RE Dominator Pro - some settings required
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365997
Failing to Boot Ubuntu 16.10 in MSI GP72
http://askubuntu.com/questions/838212/failing-to-boot-ubuntu-16-10-in-msi-gp72
[SOLVED] MSI GT72S 6QE - Freezes on boot unless acpi=off is used
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303544