# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on an MSI GE62VR 7RF

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, msi

I wanted to install Ubuntu 16.04LTS on my MSI GE62VR 7RF (i7-7700, Nvidia GTX1060 6GB). I want it to dual boot with the windows that comes preinstalled with the laptop.

I tried installing the OS, and for some reason, as soon as the setup is finished and the command for "Your system must be restarted to complete the installation" or some message of that sort shows up and I click "Reebot now", the system freezes. I then hardware shutdown the system, and when I boot into the system, it continues till it shows me the login screen. The cursor moves here, but I cannot enter my password, or click on anything on the screen.

Any leads on this will be greatly appreciable

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Issues are often more common by brand, so other models may have same issue. This may be similar? [SOLVED] MSI GT72S 6QE - Freezes on boot unless acpi=off is used
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303544

Comment: I did turn Secure boot off and also followed the instructions given on that thread. However, it didn't work.

Comment: Do not know if these threads have any different suggestions. MSi GT72VR-6RE Dominator Pro - some settings required
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365997
Failing to Boot Ubuntu 16.10 in MSI GP72
http://askubuntu.com/questions/838212/failing-to-boot-ubuntu-16-10-in-msi-gp72

Answer (score 0):

Try to install ubuntu with nomodeset mode...
To do this press e button choosing INSTALL UBUNTU in the insatallation menu and add the word nomodeset after quite splash.
After installing ubuntu, the os will not boot properly. To fix this select your ubuntu os after appearing the dual boot selection menu.Dont press Enter.Just select it and press e.
Then add nouveau.modeset=0 after quite splash and then the os will boot without any error.
But in this case the os is running using your  Nvidia gpu and your battery will drain faster. You can't switch to your intel graphics because if you do it, the OS will not boot again. To fix this error visit the below link...

[Click here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1045015/823467)