# Nvidia Graphics Error in MSI Laptop

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, msi

I have a MSI GL62M 7rdx laptop and I dual booted it with Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 in nomodeset mode. When I running ubuntu I realized that Battery life of my laptop is limited only for 1.5 hours and my laptop is heating too much and fans working fast because it is running using my gtx1050 GPU. So I changed into Intel(Power Saving mode) in Nvidia X Server Settings and after rebooting my laptop It will Freeze in some codes. How can I fix this thing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution...
when the dual boot grub menu appeared, highlight your ubuntu(linux) os using the cursors and then press e.
after that add the below code after quiet splash

```
acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009'
```

You have to type these text in every time you boot your ubuntu os. TO overcome this you have to edit your default grub using grub customizer application.

you can install it using following codes

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

After that open your grub customizer and open general settings tab and edit the kernal parameters as follows

```
quiet splash acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009'
```

[Click here to view the sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saSHQ.png)