# Installing Ubuntu on freeDOS msi PE72 7RD

Tags: boot, usb, msi

I have installed and bootable usb with ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. I have changed to UEFI mode.
First of all, I directly ask for install UBUNTU, then when it took like 2 hours I poweroff.

Then I tried to "try ubuntu without installing" and It happens the same. What should I do ?

Also I cheked if there is any error, it says no, then it says presss enter and I get something like this. 
namespace lookup failure linux ae_not_found psargs-364

More info: I have already the latest version of UEFI/BIOS, and I downloaded ubuntu with grub2.

Thank you

Comment: No, nothing.. and normally it is installed in 30-40 min. And it is the Ubuntu logo with 3 pointt light on of 5

Comment: Is issue similar to these threads? Failing to Boot Ubuntu 16.10 in MSI GP72
http://askubuntu.com/questions/838212/failing-to-boot-ubuntu-16-10-in-msi-gp72
[SOLVED] MSI GT72S 6QE - Freezes on boot unless acpi=off is used
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303544

Comment: No, I don't know how to go to grub if it is frozen UBUNTU logo with points...

Comment: You get to grub before screen shows. It should be escape with UEFI, between UEFI screen & grub screen (wh8ich may not be shown) or just after UEFI screen. May have to try more than once. If fast boot on in UEFI you may not even have time to press any key. If BIOS it is shift key not Escape key.

Comment: I have the latest bio, wo that's no the problem. And I downloaded ubuntu 16 with grup2. So any of those answers help me.

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed it a USB 3. And nothing to change on the BIOS, only the boot option.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you please [edit] your post to clarify thanks.