# Blank screen with only mouse cursor (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: gnome, graphics, 18.04, xorg, gdm

So, I've been experiencing this issue lately. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, GDM/Gnome, default Ubuntu desktop. My graphics driver is `nvidia-390` from the `graphics-drivers` PPA. My graphics card is a GeForce GTX 960M.

There have been two incidents where my display freezes and I'm unable to get into a TTY, so I shut down and restart by power cycling. Then, I get to the login screen and login, only to get a blank screen with only the cursor.

Now, If I go into a TTY and look at `Xorg.0.log`, there's one weird thing: Xorg seems to think all of my devices are keyboards. I can't post a copy of it, unfortunately. If I look at `journalctl --human`, I see a lot of lines saying that `i2c_hid_get_input` generates incomplete report. I am not sure how to interpret those.

The first time, I fixed it by reinstalling the system. Now I really don't want to do this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I use an external monitor. My laptop's monitor stays black with a cursor blinking, Whenever I restart I can only login using a tty, on my laptop's monitor. Then it turns black and I can type `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`.
Graphics start on my external monitor, but my laptop's monitor stays black with the cursor...
I am using nvidia-396, this is the recommended driver for my GeForce 1010.
Try an external monitor see if it gets recognized.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might resolve by this [solution.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198484/1027015)

Adding the `nomodeset` parameter instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded. As explained [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/207177/1027015)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. (`Ubuntu 18.04 Dell precision 7550`)

The solution below worked for me:

> 1. Secure boot off.
> 2. Run the following command on the terminal:
>
>    ```
>    sudo ubuntu-drivers install
>    ```
> 3. Restart.