# /dev/sda2: clean, ***/*** files, ***/*** blocks

Tags: boot

My LG gram 15 laptop runs Ubuntu 16.04. When I was running both Makefile and gradle simultaneously, it was getting slower and slower, and finally it froze, so, I rebooted my laptop. Then it started to print only:

```
/dev/sda2: clean, ***/*** files, ***/*** blocks
```

Where the *** are large numbers.

CLI mode works well, but I couldn't start the Ubuntu in GUI mode (lightdm, GNOME...)

I searched for a solution. I read almost every relevant answer about this problem, but none of them worked. I tried to reinstall the Nvidia driver, but my computer doesn't have an Nvidia graphics card.

Results of `df -h --exclude=tmpfs --exclude=squashfs` :

```
Filesystem | size | Used | Avail | Use% | Mounted on  
udev |0 | 12G | 0% | /dev
/dev/sda2 | 468G | 173G | 272G | 39% | /
/dev/sda1 | 511M | 6.1M | 505M | 2% | /boot/efi
```

I typed `grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log` suggestion on recovery mode.

```
$ grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(EE) /dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied
(EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
(EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
(EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
(EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
/dev/dri/card0: failed to set DRM interface version 1.4: Permission denied.
```

After I typed `Xorg -configure`

```
List of video drivers:
amdgpu 
ati
intel
nouveau
qxl
radeon
vmware
odsetting
fbdev
vesa
using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
using system config directory "usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices
Configuration failed
Server terminated with error (2). closing log file.
```

`stratx` makes below error:

```
systemd-logind : failed to get session: PID 962 does not belong to any known session
open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

**"journalctl -xe -p err -k"**

Couldn't get size: 0x8000000000000000e

MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list

Couldn't get size: 0x8000000000000000e

ip_local_port_range: prefer different parity for start/end values.

Something spring to my mind is that, I forced power off my laptop while It was connected to external monitor via HDMI cable.

Comment: Did you run out of disk space or inodes? what are the outputs of `df -h --exclude=tmpfs --exclude=squashfs` and/or `df -i --exclude=tmpfs --exclude=squashfs`

Comment: @steeldriver  Thank you for your answer. result of "df -h --exclude=tmpfs --exclude=squashfs" is 
udev|0|12G|0%|/dev
/dev/sda2|468G|173G|272G|39%|/
/dev/sda1|511M|6.1M|505M|2%|/boot/efi

Comment: @steeldriver
Sorry ! I made It easy to be read

Comment: @MukeshSaiKumar

shell disappears and a cursor appears and It keeps blinking on a black screen.

Comment: Ok, I will appended result on my question.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/384601/349837). I would check the logs with something like `journalctl -xe -p err -k`

Comment: I typed "journalctl -xe -p err -k" . I appended at the end of my question what the command says.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dev/sda1: clean, ..." This message appears after I startup my laptop, then it won't continue booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882385/dev-sda1-clean-this-message-appears-after-i-startup-my-laptop-then-it-w)

Answer (score 0):

This message is normal. This message tells you that there are no errors in your disk.

I think your display drivers are corrupt. Also if your hardware is not Nvidia, why would you want to install Nvidia drivers?

You need to remove them and install the required drivers.

You need to edit your grub and boot without the display drivers by adding "nomodeset" and then fix your driver situation.

This has nothing to do with GDM. GDM is just a display manager. Try following the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198484/1027015).

Comment: Thank you for answer. 

I realized that I don't have Nvidia graphic card in my laptop. 

I was doing everything what I could do. 

Because I was so desperate. My laptop only have integrated graphic card.

I edited grub to "quiet splash nomodeset", But It still hangs on 

"/dev/sda2 clean, ***/***files, ***/*** blocks"

Something changed is the message starts to blink.

Comment: And appended a line which says "/dev/sd2 recovering journal"

Answer (score 0):

From the errors in your `Xorg.0.log`, I see that it fails to load modules. Hopefully, the solution must be to (re)install the modules and configure X to use them. This may do it (I'll delete it if it doesn't help).

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-vesa
Xorg -configure
startx
```

Hopefully, your GUI will be up and running.

Comment: installation was successful. But rest of commands made error and warning. I appended the messages at the end of my question! Thanks a lot.