# Second monitor goes black after selecting Ubuntu in the GRUB menu

Tags: boot, 18.04, multiple-monitors

I have a dual-boot installation and after choosing Ubuntu in the GRUB menu both the built-in and external monitor displays go black if the HDMI cable is connected to the laptop. If I wait about 30 seconds and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> I can boot normally. I can't access ttys when the displays go black. If I boot up without the HDMI cable connected everything run as normal and if I connect the cable after the boot I have no problem with the second screen.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a lenovo ideapad 700 with gnome 3.28.2. My kernel version is 4.15.0-42-generic. I am using nouveau drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a way to workaround this problem.
Basically what I did was to boot with [nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do) option active in the grub. After that the black screen appears but i was able to acess tty and reboot my computer. The following boot process was normal even with an external monitor connected.