# Is `nomodeset` needed to boot Ubuntu from a Macbook's disk, just as from USB?

Tags: macbook

To install single-boot Ubuntu on an Early 2011 17" MacBook Pro I went through the following steps:

- Prepare a USB flash using Etcher and the Ubuntu 18.04 ISO file.
- Press `Option`. Select to boot from USB. Press `e`, add `nomodeset` after `quiet splash`.
- This enables me to install Ubuntu, apparently successfully, but after installation and at the first reboot, the machine hangs on the purple screen.

Should [`nomodeset`](https://askubuntu.com/a/207177/1020871) be added to the start scripts when booting the OS from disk, not just the OS on USB? If yes, what needs to be modified?

My other experiment so far was slightly more successful. Installing the Arch Linux ISO, still using Etcher, on a USB makes it possible to install Arch Linux on the Macbook *and* boot properly. But the machine boots into a full-screen terminal. No KDE, etc. (but of course this is the wrong forum for that.)

Comment: I'm checking whether my question might be a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/q/38780/1020871

Comment: My question was a duplicate. (Short answer: press 'shift' during boot, insert 'nomodeset', press F10). Next up: check whether @sudodus 's answer makes it permanent. First impression is great: the screen brightness buttons work out of the box. Though the driver for the Broadcom wifi needs to be installed manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boot option `nomodeset` is used to help the graphics work with some graphics chips/cards, where the standard linux drivers do not work well.

This is independent of the boot media (so if it is needed when booting from USB it will also be needed when booting from DVD or HDD or SSD).

---

In an installed system you should edit the file `/etc/default/grub`

See this link: [Configuring GRUB 2 - /etc/default/grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#A.2Fetc.2Fdefault.2Fgrub)

You can add `nomodeset` to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

so that it becomes

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Save the file and after that run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

to get the boot option `nomodeset` active the next time you boot.

---

If you have nvidia graphics, it might be worth trying with a proprietary graphics driver to use the whole power of the chip/card, and this will only work in an installed system.

Comment: Pressing 'e' makes it possible to edit the script when booting from USB. How does one edit the script on the macbook's disk to add 'nomodeset'?

Comment: @Calaf, It is described at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#A.2Fetc.2Fdefault.2Fgrub). Scroll down to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"