# Cannot boot Ubuntu 18.04 without nomodeset

Tags: boot, 18.04, nvidia, bootloader, gpu-driver

I am new to Ubuntu. I just installed Ubuntu on a new-built PC. It stayed on the black screen after booting. I entered GRU menu using ESC, and modified the 'quiet splash' to 'nomodeset' after reading this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do). I was able to boot Ubuntu after changing to 'nomodeset'. But it doesn't seem to be a long term solution.

Before any change, this is what I received:
[image]

Here some relevant information about the pc:
1. Nvidia 2080 Ti
2. ASUS TUF X570-WiFi motherboard

It seems to me that the problem is there is no Nvidia driver installed. I guess installing Nvidia driver will fix the problem but don't know if it is correct.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe this link will help you install a proprietary nvidia driver: [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I’d like to know if installing nvidia driver solves the booting issue’.

Answer (score 2):

Updated.

After installing the Nvidia driver, the booting problem is gone:)

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for sharing your solution :-)