# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Alienware Aurora R11

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, alienware

Is there any way to install Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Alienware Aurora R11 (fitted with Nvidia 2080Ti GPU). Whenever I try to install 18.04 in it I end up getting a black screen (which I think is because of the graphics driver). [Shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdItA.jpg). I am not able to really figure out what the problem is. I was able to flawlessly install Ubuntu 20.04 in it, but failed while installing 18.04. Any source of information/work around would be of great help to me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the grub menu when you boot up? If so you can temporarily edit the grub startup line by pressing `e` and add the kernel option `nomodeset` and boot with the modified entry.

Assuming it boots o.k. you can then install the proprietary nvidia drivers.

[Here is a topic about it.](https://askubuntu.com/a/207177)

Comment: Thanks this worked.