# Ubuntu 20.04 goes blank on boot (new PC), works in safe-graphics

Tags: boot, grub2, intel-graphics, nomodeset

I have a new PC with intel i7 10700 CPU and an ASUS B560M Pro4 MOBO. I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 using Safe Graphics mode but whenever I boot, it goes to a black screen (monitor says no signal). I've tried reinstalling, downgrading my intel microcode version, and adding the dis_ucode_ldr flag on boot, but nothing has helped. I'm at a loss as to what to do, and am unable to use the new PC at all.

EDIT: Adding nomodeset appears to boot, but only in low resolution, which I can't change. I looked at Additional Drivers, and it says "No additional drivers available." How do I increase the resolution? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding 'nomodeset' to the boot parameters?

Comment: I just tried and it appears to boot. What does that mean? Is that something I should always keep on or are there drawbacks? I'm only able to do 1024x768 graphics...

Comment: Now that you're into the OS in a graphics mode, I'd update everything and check to see if there are graphics card drivers available. The nomodeset bit is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do). In one form or another, your question is likely a duplicate. If you can't graphically get a resolution that you like, you can take a look at `xrandr`.

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get upgrade. I also tried looking for intel graphics drivers, and I've either found that they're already included, or that I can install them with an app called Linux Graphics Update Tool for Linux. This tool has since been removed (https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/update-tool), so I think that many of the answers that have existed for this question are no longer applicable (and thus not a duplicate). How else might I update the graphics drivers? Or confirm if they're even missing?

Comment: You can try `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and if this doesn't get you the resolution you want (and nobody else chimes in with an answer) then you can keep using `nomodeset` and experiment with `xrandr`.

Comment: ubuntu-drivers autoinstall didn't find any drivers (only Nvdia and AMD). I tried using xrandr, but to no avail ("xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed"). Is this an issue I might be able to fix by using a different Linux OS? Should I just give up and by a dedicated GPU?

Comment: I would suggest asking a new question about xrandr and your current predicament.