# Ultrawide monitor unable to set resolution

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution

I recently acquired a Samsung ultrawide 3440x1440 monitor (model number C34H890) and am having trouble configuring it to display the correct resolution. Using `cvt` I've obtained the modeline

```
Modeline "3440x1440_60.00"  419.50  3440 3696 4064 4688  1440 1443 1453 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

which, when I attempt to `--addmode` to the relevant port, throws this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  37
  Current serial number in output stream:  38
```

Similarly, I tried to get a modeline from `get-edid | parse-edid`, which provided

```
"Mode 7" 319.75 3440 3488 3520 3600 1440 1443 1453 1481 +hsync -vsync
```

and attempting to `--addmode` this gives the exact same error as above.

I tried using `nvidia-settings` to configure the monitor, which was half-successful. I can set the `ViewPortIn` parameter to 3440x1440, but not `ViewPortOut`, which refuses to be changed from `1920x1080`, resulting in a very blurry picture.

I also tried a fresh install of 22.04 (on a spare drive) and found that the same problems applied. I'm currently running 20.04 on a 5.11 kernel with nvidia 460 drivers.

This isn't an issue with the video card, since I have a second monitor running at 4K with no problems. The port running the problematic monitor is specced for up to 4K.

Any ideas? I've reached the limits of my knowledge of arcane Linux display systems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to solve this through software methods. My understanding is that even though my card (Quadro K620) supports up to 4K output on DisplayPort, the Linux Nvidia drivers are unable to handle the particular configuration I was attempting (one 4K monitor alongside the ultrawide described above). Nouveau was insufficient for this purpose as well.

I have a second GPU, a GeForce RTX 2060, and was able to display both monitors at the correct resolutions over that card. Hopefully Linux graphics support becomes less abysmal over the next few decades.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having issues with 3440x1440 displays, I found a solution that worked for me after days of nerve-wracking research. Here it is:

1. On the terminal, do `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.
2. Modify the following to look like this

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Note the new `nomodeset` passed to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

3. Finally, do `sudo update-grub`.

Seems there's a kernel and driver clash somewhere that happened.

Things I've tried that didn't work:

1. Adding and using a new modeline using cvt 3440 1440 60
2. Switching from Wayland to X11
3. Changing from gdm3 to lightdm
4. Doing ubuntu drivers autoinstall
5. A bunch of other configurations

I've since switched back to Wayland and gdm3, but keeping the nomodeset in.

Hope this helps anyone out there still having this issue. I really didn't want to spend on a new monitor.

Sources:

1. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=366190
2. [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)
3. [What does `nomodeset` do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do)